# Wireless internet dropping intermittently on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, wireless

This didn't happen on Ubuntu 12.04, but now I can't seem to be connected to the internet for more than 10 minutes continuously on Ubuntu 12.10.  It drops every 1-10 minutes.  It is really starting to piss me off (bad internet is my road rage).  I've tried everything else I've seen on various forums and nothing is working.  Let me know if you need any data from me and I'll try to get it for you.  Whoever helps me solve this will be my hero!

Comment: Would you consider upgrading to 13.04?

Comment: if I can do so without losing all my data on my hard drive.  Is there no solution for 12.10?

Comment: It's just that I just updated and had issues with GRUB that killed my hard drive last time....  :(

Comment: You should be able to upgrade without losing any data. But having said that, an upgrade shouldn't kill your HD. :/ Have you got backups? I just suggested that because if the wireless issues only occur with a specific version of Ubuntu, it might make sense to try another, that you might end up using at some point anyway. And perhaps the bug is fixed there. Perhaps.